# mvn versions:set not changing the child modules version when they would match their parent, which is not the same as the aggregator pom

Tags: maven, versions-maven-plugin

I am facing the need of changing the version of an aggregator maven project and the two modules it has, using `versions:set`. One of the use cases does not work and I do not know whether I'm missing something or this use case in particular is not well-supported by the plugin. Child modules versions are not updated to 1.4.0 as they would match the versions of `someother-parentartifact-1` and `someother-parentartifact-2`. I have been unable to reproduce the problem using a version different to `1.4.0` so I guessed the plugin gets confused somehow.

Aggregator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mygroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-aggregator</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0-RC1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>module-1</module>
        <module>module-2</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Module 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mygroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0-RC1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myanothergroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>someother-parentartifact-1</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myanothergroupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>some-lib</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Module 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mygroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0-RC1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myanothergroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>someother-parentartifact-2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/><!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

         (bunch of dependencies)

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Some insights:

- The parent projects of both modules are not the aggregator. This is intentional, and not to be changed unless there is no other option.
- The value of `maven.deploy.skip` does not change the outcome.
- I have only seen this when the version to be set (`1.4.0`) matches the version of the parents of the child modules.
- The command used was: `mvn versions:set -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DnewVersion=1.4.0 -DprocessAllModules`.
- Also tried to use `update-child-modules`. No success.

Some logs:

```
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------< com.mygroupId:my-aggregator >----------
[INFO] Building my-aggregator 1.4.0-RC1                                      [1/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.7:set (default-cli) @ my-aggregator ---
[INFO] Searching for local aggregator root...
[INFO] Local aggregation root: C:\somedirectory\my-aggregator
[INFO] Processing change of com.mygroupId:my-aggregator:1.4.0-RC1 -> 1.4.0
[INFO] Processing com.mygroupId:module-1
[INFO]     Updating project com.mygroupId:module-1
[INFO]         from version 1.4.0-RC1 to 1.4.0
[INFO]     Updating project com.mygroupId:module-1
[INFO]         from version 1.4.0 to 1.4.0-RC1
[INFO]
[INFO] Processing com.mygroupId:module-2
[INFO]     Updating project com.mygroupId:module-2
[INFO]         from version 1.4.0-RC1 to 1.4.0
[INFO]     Updating project com.mygroupId:module-2
[INFO]         from version 1.4.0 to 1.4.0-RC1
[INFO]
[INFO] Processing com.mygroupId:my-aggregator
[INFO]     Updating project com.mygroupId:my-aggregator
[INFO]         from version 1.4.0-RC1 to 1.4.0
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for my-aggregator 1.4.0-RC1:
[INFO]
[INFO] module-1 .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] module-2 .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] my-aggregator ......................................... SUCCESS [  3.445 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  23.637 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-04T17:02:37+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please try to add `-DprocessAllModules=true`. (https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html#processAllModules)

Comment: Same result as `-DprocessAllModules`. I have to insist, this issue only happens when `someother-parentartifact-1/2` have the same version as the one you're trying to change your project to.

Answer (score 4):

I've made this work with `mvn versions:set -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DnewVersion=1.4.0 -DoldVersion=* -DgroupId=* -DartifactId=*`